# How can I build slider-functionality within an SVG file?

Tags: javascript, svg, slider, interactive

I have an SVG image of a slider with a colored bar and a handle (see code snippet below). I want to make this SVG image interactive, so the viewer can move the handle to the eleven different positions along the slider. Everything needs to be within the `<svg></svg>` tags; I can't use external HTML or scripts. The SVG file will be added to an HTML webpage in an `<object>` tag to preserve interactivity.

Included in the SVG file are eleven invisible `<rect>` elements to act as hitboxes for each of the eleven slider positions, and a `transform="translate(0 0)"` tag on the handle group. Clicking in one of the hitboxes should move the handle to the corresponding position by updating the `transform` parameter's x-value; with the mouse button held down, moving the mouse from side to side should move the handle to the position corresponding to the x-coordinate of the mouse, even if the mouse moves vertically out of range of the hitboxes.

I know you can put JavaScript inside SVG files, but I'm not very familiar with JS so I don't know how to approach this. Is JS the best way? If so, how do I use it to get the desired functionality?

```html
<svg id="Slider-Image" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="240" height="84" viewBox="0 0 240 84">
    <defs>
        <style>
            .hitbox {
                cursor: pointer;
                opacity: 0;
            }
        </style>
    </defs>
    <g id="Slider-BG">
        <rect id="BG-Fill" width="240" height="84" fill="#999"/>
        <polygon id="Bevel-Top" points="9 29 14 35 226 35 231 29 9 29" fill="#887"/>
        <polygon id="Bevel-Right" points="226 35 226 63 231 69 231 29 226 35" fill="#aba"/>
        <polygon id="Bevel-Left" points="9 29 9 69 14 63 14 35 9 29" fill="#baa"/>
        <polygon id="Bevel-Bottom" points="9 69 231 69 226 63 14 63 9 69" fill="#cdd"/>
    </g>
    <g id="Slider-Bar">
        <rect id="Slider-Bar-BG" x="14" y="35" width="212" height="28"/>
        <rect id="Slider-Bar-Red" x="15" y="38" width="18" height="19" fill="#f22"/>
        <rect id="Slider-Bar-Yellow" x="35" y="38" width="18" height="19" fill="#ec0"/>
        <rect id="Slider-Bar-Green" x="53" y="38" width="171" height="19" fill="#9e1"/>
        <line id="Slider-Bar-Divider-1" x1="53.5" y1="38" x2="53.5" y2="57" stroke="#000" opacity="0.5"/>
        <line id="Slider-Bar-Divider-2" x1="72.5" y1="38" x2="72.5" y2="57" stroke="#000" opacity="0.5"/>
        <line id="Slider-Bar-Divider-3" x1="91.5" y1="38" x2="91.5" y2="57" stroke="#000" opacity="0.5"/>
        <line id="Slider-Bar-Divider-4" x1="110.5" y1="38" x2="110.5" y2="57" stroke="#000" opacity="0.5"/>
        <line id="Slider-Bar-Divider-5" x1="129.5" y1="38" x2="129.5" y2="57" stroke="#000" opacity="0.5"/>
        <line id="Slider-Bar-Divider-6" x1="148.5" y1="38" x2="148.5" y2="57" stroke="#000" opacity="0.5"/>
        <line id="Slider-Bar-Divider-7" x1="167.5" y1="38" x2="167.5" y2="57" stroke="#000" opacity="0.5"/>
        <line id="Slider-Bar-Divider-8" x1="186.5" y1="38" x2="186.5" y2="57" stroke="#000" opacity="0.5"/>
        <line id="Slider-Bar-Divider-9" x1="205.5" y1="38" x2="205.5" y2="57" stroke="#000" opacity="0.5"/>
    </g>
    <g id="Slider-Handle" transform="translate(0 0)">
        <polygon id="Handle-Body" points="31 66 57 66 57 46 46 35 42 35 31 46 31 66" fill="#aaa"/>
        <rect id="Handle-Center" x="42" y="35" width="4" height="31" fill="#ddd"/>
        <rect id="Handle-Pointer" x="43" y="34" width="2" height="16" fill="#111"/>
    </g>
    <g id="Slider-Positions">
        <rect id="Slider-Position-Minus-20" class="hitbox" x="15" y="29" width="19" height="40"/>
        <rect id="Slider-Position-Plus-0" class="hitbox" x="34" y="29" width="19" height="40"/>
        <rect id="Slider-Position-Plus-19" class="hitbox" x="53" y="29" width="19" height="40"/>
        <rect id="Slider-Position-Plus-38" class="hitbox" x="72" y="29" width="19" height="40"/>
        <rect id="Slider-Position-Plus-57" class="hitbox" x="91" y="29" width="19" height="40"/>
        <rect id="Slider-Position-Plus-76" class="hitbox" x="110" y="29" width="19" height="40"/>
        <rect id="Slider-Position-Plus-95" class="hitbox" x="129" y="29" width="19" height="40"/>
        <rect id="Slider-Position-Plus-114" class="hitbox" x="148" y="29" width="19" height="40"/>
        <rect id="Slider-Position-Plus-133" class="hitbox" x="167" y="29" width="19" height="40"/>
        <rect id="Slider-Position-Plus-152" class="hitbox" x="186" y="29" width="19" height="40"/>
        <rect id="Slider-Position-Plus-171" class="hitbox" x="205" y="29" width="19" height="40"/>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is something like this. The code should look a bit different when it is an independent document, but you get the idea.

```js
console.log(Math.ceil((200 - 53) / 19) * 19);
```

```html
<svg id="Slider-Image" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="240" height="84" viewBox="0 0 240 84">
  <defs>
    <style>
      #Slider-Hitbox {
        cursor: pointer;
        opacity: 0;
      }
      .divider {
        stroke: #000;
        opacity: 0.5;
      }
    </style>
  </defs>
  <g id="Slider-BG">
    <rect id="BG-Fill" width="240" height="84" fill="#999"/>
    <polygon id="Bevel-Top" points="9 29 14 35 226 35 231 29 9 29" fill="#887"/>
    <polygon id="Bevel-Right" points="226 35 226 63 231 69 231 29 226 35" fill="#aba"/>
    <polygon id="Bevel-Left" points="9 29 9 69 14 63 14 35 9 29" fill="#baa"/>
    <polygon id="Bevel-Bottom" points="9 69 231 69 226 63 14 63 9 69" fill="#cdd"/>
  </g>
  <g id="Slider-Bar">
    <rect id="Slider-Bar-BG" x="14" y="35" width="212" height="28"/>
    <rect id="Slider-Bar-Red" x="15" y="38" width="18" height="19" fill="#f22"/>
    <rect id="Slider-Bar-Yellow" x="35" y="38" width="18" height="19" fill="#ec0"/>
    <rect id="Slider-Bar-Green" x="53" y="38" width="171" height="19" fill="#9e1"/>
    <line id="Slider-Bar-Divider-1" class="divider" x1="53.5" y1="38" x2="53.5" y2="57"/>
    <line id="Slider-Bar-Divider-2" class="divider" x1="72.5" y1="38" x2="72.5" y2="57"/>
    <line id="Slider-Bar-Divider-3" class="divider" x1="91.5" y1="38" x2="91.5" y2="57"/>
    <line id="Slider-Bar-Divider-4" class="divider" x1="110.5" y1="38" x2="110.5" y2="57"/>
    <line id="Slider-Bar-Divider-5" class="divider" x1="129.5" y1="38" x2="129.5" y2="57"/>
    <line id="Slider-Bar-Divider-6" class="divider" x1="148.5" y1="38" x2="148.5" y2="57"/>
    <line id="Slider-Bar-Divider-7" class="divider" x1="167.5" y1="38" x2="167.5" y2="57"/>
    <line id="Slider-Bar-Divider-8" class="divider" x1="186.5" y1="38" x2="186.5" y2="57"/>
    <line id="Slider-Bar-Divider-9" class="divider" x1="205.5" y1="38" x2="205.5" y2="57"/>
  </g>
  <g id="Slider-Handle" transform="translate(0 0)">
    <polygon id="Handle-Body" points="31 66 57 66 57 46 46 35 42 35 31 46 31 66" fill="#aaa"/>
    <rect id="Handle-Center" x="42" y="35" width="4" height="31" fill="#ddd"/>
    <rect id="Handle-Pointer" x="43" y="34" width="2" height="16" fill="#111"/>
  </g>
  <rect id="Slider-Hitbox" x="13" y="34" width="214" height="30"/>
  <script>//<![CDATA[
    var down = false;
    var translateX = 0;
    const toSVGPoint = (svg, x, y) => {
      let p = new DOMPoint(x, y);
      return p.matrixTransform(svg.getScreenCTM().inverse());
    };
    document.getElementById("Slider-Hitbox").addEventListener("mousedown", e => {
      down = true;
      let p = toSVGPoint(document.getElementById("Slider-Image"), e.clientX, e.clientY);
      let translateX = Math.ceil((p.x-53) / 19) * 19;
      if(translateX < 0) translateX = -20;
      if(translateX > 171) translateX = 171;
      document.getElementById("Slider-Handle").setAttribute("transform", `translate(${translateX} 0)`);
    });
    document.getElementById("Slider-Image").addEventListener("mousemove", e => {
      if(down) {
        let p = toSVGPoint(document.getElementById("Slider-Image"), e.clientX, e.clientY);
        let translateX = Math.ceil((p.x-53) / 19) * 19;
        if(translateX < 0) translateX = -20;
        if(translateX > 171) translateX = 171;
        document.getElementById("Slider-Handle").setAttribute("transform", `translate(${translateX} 0)`);
      }
    });
    document.getElementById("Slider-Image").addEventListener("mouseup", e => {
      down = false;
    });
  //]]></script>
</svg>
```

This is the entire SVG with JavaScript running in an object element:

```html
<object width="240" data="data:image/svg+xml;base64,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"></object>
```

Comment: I want the handle to snap to the eleven marked positions instead of being able to slide continuously. I'm trying to see if I can figure out how to modify your JS to get that result.

Comment: I also notice that the handle does not move to the clicked part of the slider bar on mouse-down, but instead moves on mouse-up. I'd like it to snap to the position of the indicated hitbox on mouse-down, and then if the mouse moves sideways while the mouse button is still down the handle should snap to any new hitboxes as the mouse reaches their x-coordinates.

Comment: Okay, I got it running the way I want it by modifying your code. Should I edit your answer with my modifications, create my own answer and credit you as the original author whose code I modified, or something else? I'm also not sure if my solution can be improved any; it feels kind of hacky.

Comment: @Lawton you can just update my answer. I will review the code afterwards.

Comment: The edit queue is full right now. If you're online at the moment, I could temporarily put my modified code in my question for you to review and then move to your answer. I'll keep an eye on the edit queue until it opens up or you respond here.

Comment: @Lawton do that. I don't have time right now. I will edit it in tomorrow.

Comment: @Lawton I updated my answer with a slightly modified version.

Comment: Looks good! The handle wasn't quite aligned on the red position because that position has an offset of -20 instead of -19, but I made an edit fixing that. Otherwise it functions perfectly.